# Meaning of $R=0$, $R_{ab}=0$. $R_{abcd}=0$

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

First let me state some definition

The Einstein tensor is given by
\begin{align}
  G_{\mu\nu} = R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu} R
\end{align}
and note that
\begin{align}
G^{\mu}_{\phantom{\mu} \mu} = R^{\mu}_{\phantom{\mu}\mu} - \frac{1}{2} R g^{\mu}_{\phantom{\mu}\mu} = R-2R = -R
\end{align}
where we used $g_{\mu}^{\mu}=4$. With this we can express Ricci tensor in terms of Einstein tensor
\begin{align}
  R_{\mu\nu} = G_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} G g_{\mu\nu}
\end{align}
From this we can see $G_{\mu\nu}=0$ implies $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ and vice versa. ( for 4d)

What i confused is following 
suppose $R_{ab}=0$ 
Then $ R_{ab} = g^{cd} R_{acbd} =0$ since $g$ has inverse, we can deduce $R_{acbd}=0$

Is this results comes from 4d?

Am i correct?

---

cf. 
What i want to know is the meaning of $R=0$, $R_{ab}=0$. $R_{abcd}=0$.

Firstly, i know $R_{abcd} =0 $ implies $R_{ab}=0$ and $R_{ab}=0$ implies $R=0$. 
Is inverse relation also true?

Comment: No, $R_{ab} = 0$ does not imply $R_{abcd} = 0$.

Comment: A simple example is that any gravitational wave metric has $R_{ab}=0$ but $R_{abcd}\neq0$

Comment: From a more simple linear algebra approach: You perform a contraction over _two_ indices. This is basically a matrix where you multiply vectors from left and right $\vec{v}\cdot M \cdot \vec{w}$. Knowing that $M^{-1}$ exists you can say that $M \vec{w}$ can't be zero but you know nothing about hte final result. The image of $\vec{w}$ under $M$ could very well be orthogonal to $\vec{v}$.

Comment: There are no free indices in $g^{cd}R_{abcd}=0$. Therefore, the fact that $g$ is invertible is irrelevant: there is no way to isolate $R$ by multiplying by $g^{-1}$. It is similar to $\text{tr}(AB)=0\not\Rightarrow B=0$ even if $A^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, How about $g^{cd} R_{abcd} = A_{ab}$? Can i write $R_{abcd} = A_{ab}g_{cd}$?

Comment: @phy_math no, because $R_{abcd}$ is ske-symmetric in its lower indices $cd$, i.e., $R_{abcd}=-R_{abdc}$. On the other hand, $A_{ab}g_{cd}$ is symmetric in $cd$, i.e., $A_{ab}g_{cd}=+A_{ab}g_{dc}$. This means these expressions cannot be equal.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform. my former question is somehow wrong, as you mention. $g^{cd} R_{abcd} =0$ from symmetry and anti-symmetry properteis of $g$ and $R$. what i want to do  is a problem like $A_{ab} = B_{acbd} g^{cd}$  for general matrix $A, B$ and usual metric $g$. In this case can i write $R_{abcd} = A_{ab} g_{cd}$?

Comment: @phy_math you got me lost there... $R_{abcd}$ is no longer the Riemann tensor? what are $A$ and $B$, and how are they related to $R$? in your last sentence, do you perhaps mean $B_{abcd}=A_{ab}g_{cd}$, instead of $R_{abcd}=A_{ab}g_{cd}$? Anyway, in general we dont expect that tensors can be factorised into $T_{abc\cdots}=g_{ab}Q_{c\cdots}$, except for very specific tensors $T,Q$, and only for very simple geometries. In general, you cannot do what you are trying to do: if both indices of the metric are contracted, there is no way to get the whole tensor back, except for some very specific cases

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each of $R_{abcd} = 0$, $R_{ab} = 0$, and $R=0$ implies different things. $R_{abcd} =0$ is the strongest condition, and if this vanishes, then all contractions of it vanish, and hence:

$$R_{abcd} = 0\quad \Rightarrow \quad R_{ab} = 0, \quad R=0.$$

If $R_{abcd} =0$, the metric is either flat space or some identification of it.

A weaker condition is $R_{ab} = 0$ (this condition is called Ricci flatness), which can be true even if $R_{abcd} \neq 0$. A good example is Schwarzschild, which has non-trivial curvature, but is a vacuum Einstein solution and so $R_{ab} =0$. Taking a trace yields

$$ R_{ab} = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad R = 0. $$

The weakest condition of the three is $R=0$, which can be true for $R_{abcd} \neq 0$, $R_{ab} \neq 0$. A good example of this is Reissner-Nordstrom in 4D: the black hole is not vacuum so $R_{ab} \propto T_{ab} \neq 0$ (there is some non-trivial stress tensor), but the trace of the stress tensor vanishes, so that $R=T=0$.

Comment: Also, the general physical meaning of $R_{ab} = 0$ is that the stress-energy tensor vanishes at that point in spacetime, or more loosely, there is no matter or energy at that spot.

Answer (score 0):

Surgical Commander's answer is perfect. I just want to add that Riemann tensor is a (1,3) rank tensor. When a tensor is zero, then since contraction is a sum of components in a basis, all the contractions that one can built from that tensor are zero!